# What is the use of the Console class in java? Is it referring to the java control panel console? Please explain in detail

Tags: java

The java docs says "Methods to access the character-based console device, if any, associated with the current Java virtual machine.".What is the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: In shorts, it's a class to interact the the command prompt. (assuming windows)

Comment: Is the Java Control Panel a character based device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly: the console = the terminal = the command line.

That is the (usually) black screen that you can use to start your program (with `java YourClass`), and where you can read parameters from or write to.

The `Console` object is an easier-to-use alternative to `System.in` and `System.out`

Comment: Then the Console class has nothing to with the java control panel(javacpl.exe)?

Comment: @Rekha: no, nothing whatsoever. Why would you think it somehow relates to that?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, it would refer to the Command Line (what some people mistakenly refer to as DOS). In *nix systems, it would refer to the Terminal.

The Console class contains methods to handle the command line/terminal, such as reading and writing to it.